# File access System.IO.Exception after CopyEnhMetaFile() even though DeleteEnhMetaFile() is called

Tags: winapi

I am using the below code to get an `IntPtr` to an EMF file on the clipboard. The file is created without error, but when I try to delete the file in Windows Explorer while my application is still running, I get this exception:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'xyz.emf' because it is being used by another process.'

I also tried using `New MetaFile(ptr, False)` and manually calling `DeleteEnhMetaFile()`, but the error stays the same.

```vb
 Dim ptr As IntPtr = NativeMethods.GetClipboardData(14)
 If Not ptr.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then

     Using mf As New Metafile(ptr, True)

         NativeMethods.CopyEnhMetaFile(ptr, $"{somePath}\{fileName}.emf")
         'NativeMethods.DeleteEnhMetaFile(ptr)

     End Using
 End If
```

How should I clean up the `IntPtr` to the EMF file so that I can delete the file after the above code has run?

**EDIT**: I even cannot delete the file from within my application while it is still running.

Comment: The awesome problem space that is non-deterministic destruction. If you need deterministic observable behavior, don't choose a platform that cannot deliver (such as the CLR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `DeleteEnhMetaFile()` (or assign ownership to a `Metafile`) on the copied handle returned by `CopyEnhMetaFile()`, not on the handle returned by `GetClipboardData()`. The clipboard owns the original handle.

```vb
Dim ptr As IntPtr = NativeMethods.GetClipboardData(14)
If Not ptr.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then

    Dim ptrCopy as IntPtr = NativeMethods.CopyEnhMetaFile(ptr, $"{somePath}\{fileName}.emf")
    ...
    NativeMethods.DeleteEnhMetaFile(ptrCopy)

End If
```